# Delete stripe customer default source with stripe android API

Tags: android, kotlin, stripe-payments

We set customer default source with CustomerSession

```
 CustomerSession.getInstance().setCustomerDefaultSource(
                    this,
                    customerSource.getId(),
                    customerSource.getSourceType(),
                    listener);
```

But can I set null or remove default source of customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delete sources (by any means) using the Stripe Android SDK via the CustomerSession or PaymentSession.  You need to do that through your backend.

Comment: Yes @korben, I have to do it in backend, unfortunately stripe doesn't support android as its needed